# How to keep my keys in safe in react native (expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have 3 release channels - dev, qa, prod.

```
const ENV_MODES = {
  dev: {

  },
  prod: {

  },
  qa: { 

  }
}

ENV_MODES.default = ENV_MODES.prod

const getEnvVars = channel => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return ENV_MODES.dev
  if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') return ENV_MODES.prod
  if (channel.startsWith(ENV_DEV)) return ENV_MODES.dev
  if (channel.startsWith(ENV_QA)) return ENV_MODES.qa
  if (channel.startsWith(ENV_PROD)) return ENV_MODES.prod
  return ENV_MODES.default
}

const ENV = getEnvVars(Constants.manifest.releaseChannel)
```

But I don't want to put keys into the repo.
How should I handle this? As I understand I can't expect that I will have `NODE_ENV  === 'qa'` when I will publish in QA channel

Answer (score 3):

You could use [react-native-dotenv](https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv) and add your keys to a `.env` file and add it to `.gitignore`. This way you won't be pushing keys to your repo and you can change your variables depending on the environment your code is running on.

To use the lib you only need to add it to your `devDependencies` and add it to you `babel.config.js` file, like so:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'babel-preset-expo',
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
    ],
  };
};
```

**EDIT**:

`NODE_ENV` won't be the same as your release channel. If you want to load configs based on the release channel use `Expo.Constants.manifest.releaseChannel`.

However have in mind this variable doesn't exist in Dev mode, as per expo's docs.

> Expo.Constants.manifest.releaseChannel does NOT exist in dev mode. It does exist, however when you explicitly publish / build with it.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's an example on how you can achieve both individual configurations for each release channel and use `react-native-dotenv` to avoid pushing secrets to your Git repo (since this is a big no no).

**Remember**: add your `.env` file to your `.gitignore`.

#### Constants.js

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { AWS_KEY } from 'react-native-dotenv';
import { Constants as ExpoConstants } from 'expo';

const getChannelConfigs = (releaseChannel = '') => {
  switch (releaseChannel) {
    case 'qa':
      return {
        API_URL: 'https://qa.com/api',
        ...
      };

    case 'prod':
      return {
        API_URL: 'https://prod.com/api/',
        ...
      };

    default:
      return {
        API_URL: 'https://dev.com/api/',
        ...
      };
  }
};

const CHANNEL_CONFIGS = Object.freeze(getChannelConfigs(ExpoConstants.manifest.releaseChannel));

export default { AWS_KEY, CHANNEL_CONFIGS };
```

#### .env

```
AWS_KEY='superSecretKeyDoNOTStealThx'
```

In this example we are configuring which API URL the app will call based on its release channel. We're also avoiding commiting keys to our Git repo, since we now have them in a cozy `.env` file.

It's also worth mentioning this setup works when building a standalone app in your CI, but handing secret keys to your users might not be the best idea.

Comment: The question is will I have NODE_ENV === `qa` when I will publish in `qa` channel by `expo publish --release-channel qa`?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to better address your questions, but  maybe edit the question so it becomes a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide some example of how and where to load this config (I use keys for AWS) and how not store them inside repo? Everywhere I see examples where variables inside the env.js file which is in the repo.

Comment: Yeah, I can. I'm on mobile so maybe in 2hrs I'll update the answer again.

Comment: @Praud added an example. If this answers all your doubts I'll ask you to accept my answer as the correct one. If you still need something more feel free to ask.

Comment: Okay, I see. And what if I need to use different API keys in different channels? This is my main concern...
I have to use different tokens in different channels. Different google api key and so on.

Comment: @Praud have your CI handle that, create steps where depending on the release channel the `.env` is populated differently.

Comment: @Praud if this answered all your questions please remember to select this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Expo now has eas.json file that sits in root of your app. That file can define all the build profiles and variables if needed. The submit feature of the configuration helps manage all the app store related configs.

Sensitive secrets (prod ids and paths) , feature flags are all possible to configure.
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/

```
{
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "node": "16.13.0",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://company.com/api"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "extends": "production",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://staging.company.com/api"
      }
    }
  }
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "serviceAccountKeyPath": "../path/to/api-xxx-yyy-zzz.json",
        "track": "internal"
      },
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "john@turtle.com",
        "ascAppId": "1234567890",
        "appleTeamId": "AB12XYZ34S"
      }
    }
  }
}
```